# Run single test using Python Unittest in Visual Studio Code Debug mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I use the pylint extension in Visual Studio Code within the Debug module (see image) to run my tests using Python Unittest library.

Whenever I run my tests, I execute my test.py file in Debug and it runs all of the tests in the entire file.  I have my tests broken up logically by classes with several tests per class.

To reduce the time it takes evaluate test results for a single test I am actively working on, is there a way to execute just that one test rather than wait for all the tests in the test.py file to execute while in VS Code Debug mode?

For example:

```
test.py

import unittest

class test_TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Test1(self):
        x = 1
        self.assertEqual(x, 1)

    def test_Test2(self):
        y = 2
        self.assertEqual(y, 3)
```

If I want to only execute test_Test2() to make sure that it fails, how do I do that without running the entire file (i.e., test_Test1 and test_Test2)?

[image]

Comment: You mean other than the "Debug Test" code lens?

Comment: @BrettCannon I edited the question to add some additional clarification that hopefully helps.  Not sure I quite follow what you mean as it relates to Debug Test code lens?  Is code lens in reference to a separate extension to install?

Comment: I went ahead and answered the question with my response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your tests are discovered by `Python: Run All Unit Tests` (or clicking on the `Run Tests` button in the status bar and choosing `Discover Unit Tests`), a code lens is provided to run individual test functions, methods, and classes either normally or under the debugger.

[image]

Clicking on `Debug Test` will run open the debugger and run the unit test under it. Otherwise you can modify your `launch.json` to add a debug configuration and specify the arguments to your test runner to just run the test(s) you're interested in.

Comment: I was able to discover the tests and run them using the methods you described above but I never had the code lens options appear above the test methods.  Do you have a separate code lens extension installed, and if so, which one do you have?  BTW, I'm running on Windows on VS Code Version 1.21.1.  Thanks.

Comment: No, this is built into the extension. At this point could you file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python ?

Comment: just as I was drafting up my issue, it started working!  Thank you!